# Calculating t-statistics of the cross section

Tags: descriptive-statistics, cross-section

I am looking at a summary statistics table in a finance paper, which is from a panel data set. The table is something like this:

```
Variable       Mean     Median      t-stat
SR           0.026       0.018      25.210
Size         2715.420    308869     33.840
```

I want to understand how the t-stats here are calculated. The description for the table says this:

> The time-series mean, median and t-statistics of the cross-sectional average value of variables are reported

So my interpretation is that, for each cross section, we calculate the mean and the median. And then average it among all the years to get the Mean and Median. What about the t-stat? What means are compared to get the t-stat?

Appreciate it if someone explain the procedure and the reasoning.